# Cloud Firestore Error: Function Query.startAfter() requires a valid first argument, but it was undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm implementing Infinite Scroll with Cloud Firestore and using the lastVisible as the document reference to know where to being the refreshing queries for another 5 users (limit is set to 5).

The issue is coming from "lastVisible" and is returning as undefined at the line. It adds the lastVisible to the visibles array in state when running the initial "retrieveUsers" function, but not in the retrieveMore function.

**console.log (this.state.visibles)**

```
Visibles (Retrieve More)
Array [
  Object {
    "company": "Google",
    "first_name": "Dan",
    "last_name": "Jones",
    "email": null,
    "phone_number": "(553) 402-8023",
  },
  undefined,
]
Paginated Query starting (Retrieve More)
```

The issue is with adding a second, third, fourth, and etc. last visible documents to the this.state.visibles array. It's undefined, which throws off my Cloud Firestore queries due to it not knowing what the last visible document was.

The error is: "Function Query.startAfter() requires a valid first argument, but it was undefined."

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ActivityIndicator, Dimensions, FlatList, View, SafeAreaView, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import firebaseConfig from '../config/config';

// Imports: Components
import UserSelector from '../components/UserSelector';
import TitleLarge from '../components/TitleLarge';

// Screen Dimensions
const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

// Screen: Flat List (Users)
class FlatListUsers extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      limit: 5,
      visibles: [],

      loading: false,
      refreshing: false,
    };
  }

  // Component Will Mount
  componentWillMount = () => {
    // Firebase: Initialize
    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: `${firebaseConfig.apiKey}`,
      authDomain: `${firebaseConfig.authDomain}`,
      databaseURL: `${firebaseConfig.databaseURL}`,
      projectId: `${firebaseConfig.projectId}`,
      storageBucket: `${firebaseConfig.storageBucket}`,
      messagingSenderId: `${firebaseConfig.messagingSenderId}`,
    });
  }

  // Component Did Mount
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.retrieveUsers();
  }

  // Retrieve Users
  retrieveUsers = async () => {
    try {
      // Set State: Loading
      this.setState({ loading: true });

      // Firebase: Database + Settings
      const db = firebase.firestore();

      // Query
      console.log('Fetching Users')
      let initialQuery = await db.collection('licenses')
                            .where('company', '==', 'Google')
                            .orderBy('first_name')
                            .limit(5)

      // Query Snapshot
      let documentSnapshots = await initialQuery.get();

      // Document Data
      let documentData = documentSnapshots.docs.map(document => document.data());

      // Last Visible Document (To Start From For Proceeding Queries)
      let lastVisible = documentData[documentData.length - 1];

      // Set State
      this.setState({
        data: [...this.state.data, ...documentData],
        visibles: [...this.state.visibles, lastVisible],
        loading: false,
        refreshing: false,
      });

      console.log('Last Visible');
      console.log(this.state.visibles);
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // Retrieve More Users
  retrieveMore = async () => {
    try {
      console.log('Retrieving more Users (Retrieve More)');
      this.setState({ loading: true });
      console.log('Visibles (Retrieve More)');
      console.log(this.state.visibles);

      // Firebase: Database + Settings
      const db = firebase.firestore();

      // Query
      console.log('Paginated Query starting (Retrieve More)');
      let initialQuery = await db.collection('licenses')
                            .where('company', '==', 'Google')
                            .orderBy('first_name')
                        .startAfter(this.state.visibles[this.state.visibles.length - 1])
                        .limit(5);

      // Query Snapshot
      let documentSnapshots = await initialQuery.get();

      // Last Visible Document (To Start From For Proceeding Queries)
      let lastVisible = documentSnapshots[documentSnapshots.length - 1];
      console.log('Last Visible');
      console.log(typeof this.state.lastVisible);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.lastVisible));

      // Document Data
      let documentData = documentSnapshots.docs.map(document => document.data());

      // Set State
      this.setState({
        data: [...this.state.data, ...documentData],
        visibles: [...this.state.visibles, lastVisible],
        loading: false,
        refreshing: false,
      });
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // Render Header
  renderHeader = () => {
    try {
      return (
        <View style={styles.activityIndicator}>
          <TitleLarge title="Users" />
        </View>
      )
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // Render Footer
  renderFooter = () => {
    try {
      // Check If Loading
      if (this.state.loading) {
        return <ActivityIndicator />
      }
      else {
        return null;
      }
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => ( 
            <UserSelector
              firstName={item.first_name}
              lastName={item.last_name}
              company={item.company}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
          onEndReached={()=> {
            if (this.state.loading === false) {
              this.retrieveMore();
            }
          }}          
          onEndReachedThreshold={0}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
}

// Styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: height,
    width: width,
    borderTopWidth: 0,
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
  },
  scrollView:{
    height: 'auto',
  },
  userContainer: {
    width: width,
    marginBottom: 7,
  },
  itemText: {
    fontFamily: 'System',
    fontSize: 17,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: '#222222',
    marginLeft: 16,
  },
  activityIndicator: {
    paddingVertical: 20,
    borderTopWidth: 0,
    borderTopColor: '#CED0CE',
  },
});

// Exports
export default FlatListUsers
```

Comment: At initial state, `this.state.visibles` is [] and `this.state.visibles.length` is 0 ?. So 
  first argument of Query.startAfter() is undefind. Because `this.state.visibles[this.state.visibles.length - 1]` is `this.state.visibles[-1]`.

Comment: It's adding the first "visible" in the function "retrieveUsers," which has the "first_name": "Dan" and "last_name": "Jones." However, I don't see why the same logic isn't working in the "retrieveMore" function?

Comment: At first, you check message `console.log(this.state.visibles);`. And try `this.state.loading` initial state set `true`.

Comment: There's two of those statements. One one "retrieveUsers" and the other in "retrieveMore." The "retrieveUsers" console.log works, but the "retrieveMore" returns undefined.

 I am also getting the warning: "Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle."

Comment: Did you try `this.state.loading` initial state set `true` in `constructor()`? 
The error is depends on react native. I am not very familiar with react native. Sorry.